# Does time complexity become O(n) when return value of myArray.reversed() is assigned to a previously initialized array? Copy-on-write?

Tags: arrays, swift

Apple docs state Time Complexity is O(1) for the .reversed() method.

In the following code, `arr` (line 2) is a `ReversedCollection<Array<Int>>` type.

How come printing `arr` (line 3) doesn't return the numbers in reversed order?

```
// 1 -  let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// 2 -  let arr = a.reversed()   // <- O(1) is the complexity of this operation.
// 3 -  print(arr)               // unexpected - prints ReversedCollection<Array<Int>>(_base: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Regarding the following code sample - Converting the `ReversedCollection` to an `Array` (line 2) returns values in reversed order as expected in a new array. Additional storage was allocated. I understand `a.reversed()` operation itself is O(1). There is no question about that. I do not understand how this operation remains O(1) after converting its output to a newly initialized array. Apple's docs show this conversion to an `Array` & directly below it they mention O(1). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice/1688969-reversed

Did Apple fail to state that the time & space complexity both change after line 2 completes execution?

```
// 1 -  let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// 2 -  let arr = Array(a.reversed())    // arr is type Array<Int>
// 3 -  print(arr)                       // prints [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] as expected
```

In the following code, (line 3) - `a.reversed()` return value is type `ReversedCollection<Array<Int>>`, which is then assigned to `arr` - type `Array<Int>`. I am concerned this assignment to arr operation removes the O(1) time complexity; it appears similar to the code above(line 2)  - where we converted the `ReversedCollection<Array<Int>>` to an `Array`.

Is the code below the same as the code directly above?

Does time complexity remain O(1) after execution of line 3 completes in the code below?

```
// 1 -  let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// 2 -  var arr = a                   // arr is type Array<Int>
// 3 -  arr = arr.reversed()          // assigns a ReversedCollection<Array<Int>> to an Array
// 4 -  print(type(of: arr)           // prints Array<Int>     
// 5 -  print(arr)                    // print [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] as expected
```

Another scenario is shared below - (line 3) - Error is returned - unable to assign `rev` to `arr`. I present it to compare against the code directly above (line 3), which assigns the `ReversedCollection` type to the `Array` type in 1 less step than in the code below.

```
// 1 -  let a = [1, 2, 3]
// 2 -  let rev = a.reversed()       // arr is type Array<Int>
// 3 -  let arr = rev                // Error - Cannot assign value of type 'ReversedCollection<[Int]>' to type '[Int]'
```

Regarding the sample code below, (line 3) - This time I'm not assigning `arr.reversed()` to `arr`. It results in `arr` not being reversed, which is not what I expected. I wanted to avoid using `.reverse()` in line 3 because that runs in O(n).

```
// 1 -  let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
// 2 -  var arr = a                   // arr is type Array<Int>
// 3 -  arr.reversed()                // does not reverse arr's items    
// 5 -  print(arr)                    // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - not what I initially expected
```

Is **copy-on-write** keeping time complexity O(1) even after `ReversedCollection` is assigned / converted to an `Array`?

Comment: "Apple's docs show this conversion to an Array & directly below it they mention O(1)." You should link us to the documentation that makes these claims

Comment: Question updated

Comment: This is just a misunderstanding. The `O(1)` applies only to producing reversed collection. Copying it an array or string is linear time.

Comment: @japsoccer has **"Another scenario is shared below - (line 3) - Error is returned - unable to assign rev to arr"**  then you show `// 3 -  let arr = rev                // Error - Cannot assign value of type 'ReversedCollection<[Int]>' to type '[Int]'` there is no way for this to happen. Array is a type inferred language. You are creating a new object and that would result in  `ReversedCollection<[Int]>`

Comment: Your screenshot isn't particularly exploring copy-on-write. Multiple `Array` addresses can reference the same underling `ArrayBuffer` (which is the thing that is being optimized by CoW, not the `Array`). There's no CoW going on here anyway, but your test cases wouldn't tell us even if there were.

Comment: Testing memory addresses in Playgrounds is incredibly misleading. Playgrounds operate in a really unusual environment, where each line is somewhat independent. I would expect very different results from a command-line app (and though not in this case, you can often get different results from an optimized command-line app than a non-optimized one.)

Comment: It's possible you're envisioning a kind of magic that doesn't exist. Array is slightly magical in Swift and the compiler has special cases to deal with it, but ReversedCollection is just Swift code. "Copy on write" isn't actually part of Swift at all. It's something that's implemented by hand in various stdlib collections (and that you can implement yourself if you want). It's not something the compiler does.

Comment: You might find Mike Ash's excellent blog post helpful here in understanding what "copy on write" means: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html

Answer (score 5):

The result of `.reversed()` is just a structure that iterates backwards over the collection. It costs a constant time to create. Iterating over it costs O(n) just like any collection.

So `let rev = a.reversed()` is O(1), but `let rev = Array(a.reversed())` is O(n) since it iterates over `a` to make the copy. There is no implicit conversion. `Array` and `ReversedCollection<Array>` are completely different types. You can pass any Sequence to [`Array.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2853698-init) and it will copy the values into a new Array.

Stdlib is open source, so you can also look at [how it's all implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Reverse.swift). You'll see that the initializer is only an assignment:

```
internal init(_base: Base) {
  self._base = _base
}
```

Comment: If copy-on-write was used that would be an important factor. I ran a couple tests to check it out, but it's possible it wasn't done thoroughly. The question has been updated to reflect what occurred. Any thoughts about that @RobNapier?

Comment: Copy-on-write isn't relevant here. If you can explain what causes you to think it would be relevant, I can discuss why it isn't, but I can't picture why you think it would be. ReversedCollection is not mutable (it doesn't conform to MutableCollection), so I don't know what "write" you're thinking about. In a very big-picture kind of way, the CoW system allows `self._base = _base` to be O(1), which isn't technically something you get for free in Swift. But that's *really* nitpicky IMO.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, Array.reversed() is an O(1) operation. It just wraps the original Array with logic that automatically adjusts the indexes as you access them for an effective reversal.

If you explicitly create a new Array from a Reversed collection, you are creating a full copy of the data and you are going to pay the O(n) cost. I don't think Swift's copy-on-write optimizations apply here.

Here is a code snippet that you could run to see the time complexity.

```
var array = [Int]()
for i in 0..<1000000 {
    array.append(i)
}

let startDate = Date()
let reversed = array.reversed() // O(1)
print(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)) // ~0s from start

var newArray = Array(reversed) // O(n)
print(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)) // ~0.2s from start

newArray[0] = 0
print(Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)) // ~0.2s from start
```